# How can I align this submit button using CSS

Tags: html, css

I am new to CSS, and I am writting a web page with a form that has submit button, but I am not able to align well the submit button within the form

this is what I get with this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtWcy.png)

I don know how can I fix this, so any help is very appreciated.

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: blue;
}
body {
  background-color: #1AD5EA;
  text-align: center;
}
form {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
td {
  /* text-align: center; */
  font-weight: bold;
}
input[type=submit] {
  padding: 5px 55px;
  border: 5 none;
  border-radius: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css">
  <title>Nuevo cliente</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Introduzca los datos del nuevo cliente</h1>
  <br/>


  <form action="procesar_form.php" method="post">

    <table>

      <tr>
        <td>Nombre</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="nombre">
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Direcci&oacuten</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="direccion">
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Tel</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="tel">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <br>
          <br>
          <input align="center" type="submit" value="Enviar">
        </td>
      </tr>

    </table>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Where do you want the button to go?

Comment: Just feedback about your HTML, you shouldn't use HTML tables for general layout purposes. Tables should be used for tabular data only.

Comment: right, to be visually  good under the input texts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the button to be aligned to the right, you can set the parent `td` for the submit button to `colspan="2"` so that the cell will span both columns in your table, and assign `text-align: right;`

```css
h1 {

    text-align: center;
    color: blue;

}

body {

     background-color: #1AD5EA;
     text-align: center;
}

form {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    }

td {
 /* text-align: center; */
  font-weight: bold;
}

input[type=submit] {
    padding:5px 55px;  
    border:5 none;
    border-radius: 15px;
    text-align:center; 
}


.submit {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css">
<title>Nuevo cliente</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Introduzca los datos del nuevo cliente</h1>
<br/>


<form  action="procesar_form.php" method="post">

                <table> 

                    <tr>
                        <td>Nombre</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="nombre"></td>
                    </tr> 

                    <tr>
                        <td>Direcci&oacuten</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="direccion"></td>
                    </tr>

                     <tr> 
                        <td>Tel</td> 
                        <td><input type="text" name="tel"></td> 
                    </tr>
                    <tr> 
                        <td colspan="2" class="submit"> 
                            
                            <input align="center" type="submit" value="Enviar"> 
                        </td> 
                    </tr> 

                </table> 
        </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a `table` to handle your formatting, I don't think what you're looking for needs to be a CSS answer.

In your case, if you are trying to align your button to be below the text input boxes, then you need to create a blank `td` in your last `tr` to fill the gap and align the next `td` that contains your button on the right.

```
                <tr> 
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <br><br>
                        <input align="center" type="submit" value="Enviar"> 
                    </td> 
                </tr>
```

For a CSS-only solution, the easiest next step would be to remove all `table` references and rely on CSS for positioning of all elements.

Comment: If I remove how can align the form elements vertically one below the other  ?

Comment: Look into `display` options, such as `block` and `inline-block`, as well as fixed sizes for things like `width` and `height`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want the button to go in the center:

You want to add `colspan="2"` 
in the `td` which holds you submit button

Answer (score 0):

Please try to avoid using table to position elements as that will never give you full control over your positioning and it is somewhat deprecated.

Try this.

CSS:

```
    h1 {

  text-align: center;
  color: blue;

  }

 body {

 background-color: #1AD5EA;
 text-align: center;
 width:100%;
 }

 form {
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
}

td {
/* text-align: center; */
font-weight: bold;
}

input[type=submit] {
padding:5px 55px;  
border:5 none;
border-radius: 15px;
margin:0 auto;  
}
```

HTML;

```
<form  action="procesar_form.php" method="post">

            <table> 

                <tr>
                    <td>Nombre</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="nombre"></td>
                </tr> 

                <tr>
                    <td>Direcci&oacuten</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="direccion"></td>
                </tr>

                 <tr> 
                    <td>Tel</td> 
                    <td><input type="text" name="tel"></td> 
                </tr>
                <tr> 

            </table> 
            <div> <input type="submit" value="Enviar" ></div>
    </form>
```

Comment: I used it because I was unable to get the form elements laigned vertically one below the other...

Comment: Simple, you can use a ul list, or even a div. Just style it. For ul, remove the list-style, then generally, add a fixed width and padding. Then thereafter, put your contents inside the div or list you are controlling with your class. With this, you can style your page anyhow you need it. Use float where you need it displayed side by side. Use display:block, if you need it vertically, but then add a margin-bottom or topto separate it, give your input elements a fixed width, and so on and so forth, that easy.